# cakephp beforesave question

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

I follow in book.cake and I don't know I should send something to the parameters.

```
function beforeSave() {
if (!empty($this->data['Article']['create_dt']) && !empty($this->data['Article']['modified_dt'])) {
        $this->data['Article']['create_dt'] = $this->dateFormatBeforeSave($this->data['Article']['create_dt']);
        $this->data['Article']['modified_dt'] = $this->dateFormatBeforeSave($this->data['Article']['modified_dt']);
}
return true;
}
```

I try to search example but don't found. 
I need many example
somebody  can help me to find big resource
thank for suggest

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`beforeSave` is called automatically by Cake before it saves data. In it, you can do whatever you want to do before each save. Typically this means altering `$this->data`, which is the data that is about to be saved.

The method is passed one parameter: an array of the form `array('validate' => true/false, ('fieldList' => array(...))`. This corresponds to the two extra parameters you can supply to `save()`:

```
$this->Model->save($this->data, false, array('foo', 'bar'));
```

In this case the array would look like
`array('validate' => false, 'fieldList' => array('foo', 'bar'))`.

You can accept this array by specifying an argument:

```
public function beforeSave($options) { ... }
```

`$options` will look like described above. You can use this information any way you want.

If you don't `return true` from `beforeSave`, the save operation will be canceled altogether.

That's all.

Comment: thank you <br/>
I need to record time every I create or modified data
can you guide me

Comment: +1, nice clear explanation that neatly allowed me to solve a date saving issue with MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

try using created and modified magic fields with datetime type in table cake would automatically handle them

Answer (score 0):

i want to mention, that beforeSave() should be used carefully, because it is used on every time when data is saved with this model.

if you forget that it is used, you will get unexpected results.
Happens to me several times... ;)